# Url fetch to third party server keeps timing out from cron job?

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a cron job that runs every 15 minutes. It starts a local servlet which tries to open a url from a server I have running (not part of app engine):

```
<cron>
  <url>/utils/doUpCheck</url>
  <description>Check that our third party server is up.</description>
  <schedule>every 5 minutes</schedule>
</cron>
```

in the servlet at /utils/doUpCheck:

```
String url = "https://example.com:9443/echo";
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)new URL(url).openConnection();
conn.setConnectTimeout(10000);
conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
...
```

but I'm logging a timeout exception every time it runs:

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: 
  Timeout while fetching URL: https://example.com:9443/echo
  at com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceImpl.convertApplicationException(URLFetchServiceImpl.java:142)
  ...
```

I'm sure the server at example.com is running though, it's easy to check from a browser whenever I see this error occur. Any idea why this could be happening? Of course as a sanity check, I've replaced the url with "https://google.com", and it works ok. So seems like something specific with my server, but again it works fine from other apps / browsers,

Thanks

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/urlfetch/

------- Update ----------

One other item, I recently changed the IP address of my third-party server. So maybe app engine has some stale dns entry for that domain name? Like I said earlier, other apps / browsers all resolve the domain name ok.

------- Update Again ----------

I opened up an additional port on the same machine to serve http requests (using the same webserver app instance, too). So app engine can resolve this just fine:

```
http://example.com:9000/echo
```

but I continue to get the timeouts to:

```
https://example.com:9443/echo
```

I'm sure "http://example.com:9443" is serving though, as I can hit it with any browser ok. It's also using a cert from a trusted authority, I haven't had to make any exceptions for the browsers when visiting the url.

I'm stuck here, any ideas?

------- Update Again ----------

I've added some code to try the same with the low-level URL fetch service, same problem, socket timeout exception.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/urlfetch/package-summary

Comment: Seeing that you have not solved your problem yet a suggestion would be to use httplib2 which is lower level but more powerful. https://code.google.com/p/httplib2/wiki/Examples

Comment: I'm using java, and I've tried with the low-level URL fetch service provided by app engine, it has the same problem. https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/urlfetch/package-summary

Answer (score 2):

The certificate used for https encryption on your third party server must be signed by an authority that the AppEngine software trusts.  A self signed certificate should result in a connection fail although timeout is not the expected result.  Try http instead of https as another sanity check (test that with a browser first).

Comment: Hi yes the certificate I'm using on the server is from a trusted authority (godaddy). I can hit it from chrome etc without any ssl warnings. Yeah I was expecting an ssl exception instead of a timeout if the ssl cert were the issue.

Comment: Also just added a comment about this being a stale DNS issue? - I recently changed the ip address that the domain name points to. Maybe app engine still doesn't know (the change was made around 2 weeks ago).

Comment: Most DNS entries have a time to live of less than 24 hours, I cannot believe that AppEngine would cache entries for 2 weeks.  I'd still like to see what happens if you change from https to http.

Comment: Ok after some testing, it seems the timeout is related to ssl - I have the same machine serving http from the same webserver app at a different port. When app engine tries hitting http://example.com:9000, it works fine. When it tries hitting https://example.com:9443, I get the timeouts every time. I'm sure that url is up though, since I can hit it with any browser just fine. I'm stuck here, if there's an SSL error, I would expect a track trace showing me that, but I just keep getting timeout exceptions instead.

Comment: @user1219278 just a long shot, but have you tried with the standard port 443 for SSL instead of 9443 ?

Answer (score 2):

Check how long this request normally takes.  the handler invoked by cron must respond inside 60 sec. Also you by default urlfetch service has a timeout of 5 secs. So you need to use setTimeout to give you a longer potential response time -

See https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/urlfetch/

Comment: Yes I had set the setConnectTimeout and setReadTimeout each to 10 seconds. All the timeouts occur after 19 seconds. The endpoint I'm hitting on the server returns a really small response, it's just an echo servlet for testing.